# Getting last character of string not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, discord, discord.py

Have a command for my bot that randomly selects a line from a text file and assigns it to a variable. I have a number on the end of each line (my line here.3). What the code is supposed to do is assign the last character of the line (which is now a string assigned to a variable) to a variable.

The problem is, it just doesn't do that. Well, it only does it to the last line in the text file. It does not matter what line the `random.choice()` function gets, it will always only work on the last line on the text file

```
@commands.command()
async def slap_t(self, ctx, member : discord.Member):

    with open('docs/slap_t.txt') as f:

        slap_responses = f.readlines()

        f.close()

        slap= random.choice(slap_responses)

        gif_num = slap[-1]

        print(f"response: {slap}")
        print(f"gif num = {gif_num}")
```

Comment: Maybe it is because other lines include `\n` at the end. Try again with `slap_responses = f.read().splitlines()` instead of `slap_responses = f.readlines()`.

Comment: @j1-lee What do you mean `\n`? Do you mean that they have `\n` at the end of the line?

Comment: Yes `readlines()` does not strips away the newline character (which is usually called `\n`) from each of the lines. `slap[-1]` would return this newline character, which you might think is an "error".

Comment: @j1-lee Actually you just fixed the problem. Can you make it an answer so I can flag it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because other lines in your `slap_responses` include `\n` (newline character) at the end. Try again with `slap_responses = f.read().splitlines()` instead of `slap_responses = f.readlines()`. This will strip the trailing newline from each line, and store the lines in the list `slap_responses`.

`readlines()` does not strips away `\n` from each of the lines. Therefore in your code `slap[-1]` would return this newline character, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: How would I remove the number at the end?

Comment: The number is just a character in the string (my string here3). How do I remove the last character (the number)?